# What is the syntax of the FTP log file

Tags: logging, ftp, apache2

I'm trying to go through some of my FTP logs to examine an issue I've experienced. But the log files have some shorthand flags, I don't know what they mean, and I am unable to find any sort of documentation on it.

An example of a line from the FTP log is:

```
Tue Jan 05 17:18:22 2016 0 1.2.3.4 3581 /path/to/file/file.php a _ o r username ftp 1 * c
```

Date and time are obvious, `1.2.3.4` would be my IP address, `3581` I'm assuming is the Linux PID, `username` is my FTP account username.

The ending of the line, `a _ o r username ftp 1 * c` (except for `username` and `ftp`) is what I'm most confused about. And the `0` between the date and my IP address.

Is there any documentation somewhere about what all those flags represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/mod_ftp/trunk/modules/ftp/ftp_log.c you have the following ftp-specific variables:

```
These callbacks extend mod_log_config by adding additional
% directives as follows:

%..M  The mode that was used to transfer the file.
      A single character is printed, a (ascii) or b (binary)
%..F  Any action that was taken on the file (concationated as needed)
        C - file was compressed.
        U - file was uncompressed.
        T - file was tarred.
        _ - no action taken.
%..d  Direction the file was sent.
        o - outgoing
        i - incoming
%..W  How the file was accessed.
        r - real
        a - anonymous
        g - guest
%..S    Service name, usually 'ftp'
%..Z    Authentication method
        0 - no auth
        1 - rfc931 auth
%..Y    Authenticated user id
        * - if not available
```

The "normal" Apache variables can be found here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

With a default log format of (based on https://httpd.apache.org/mod_ftp/ftp/ftp_tls.html)

```
LogFormat "%{%b %e %H:%M:%S %Y}t %T %a %B %U %M %F %d %W %u %S %Z %Y" ftp_transfer
```

Combined it seems to be:

```
Date (%{%b %e %H:%M:%S %Y}t)
The time taken to serve the request, in seconds. (%T)
Client IP address of the request (%a)
Size of response in bytes, excluding HTTP headers. (%B)
The URL path requested, not including any query string. (%U)
The mode that was used to transfer the file, a=ascii, b=binary (%M)
Any action that was taken on the file (%F)
Direction the file was sento=outgoing, i=incoming  (%d)
How the file was accessed (%W)
username (%u)
Service name, usually 'ftp' (%S)
Authentication method 0=none, 1=rfc9321 (%Z)
Authenticated user id *=n/a (%Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of that log line appears to be the [xferlog(5)](http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/doc/xferlog.html) format, traditionally used by many FTP servers.